# Can you mix and match Spring form tags and regular HTML form tags in a single HTML form?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, forms

I have a legacy HTML form that I want to make into a Spring form. Do I need to switch all of the form tags to Spring form tags or could I mix and match them as I please?

In other words, something like this:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="mymodel" action="/somecontroller/someaction" method="post">
<input type="text" name="something" value="">
</form:form>
```

instead of this (using only Spring form tags):

```
<form:form modelAttribute="mymodel" action="/somecontroller/someaction" method="post">
<form:input path="something" />
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular `<input />` elements within a `<form:form />` without any problems.  This is the conventional way to add submit buttons to a Spring form.

See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-formtag) for more information.